Shrinkwrapping with amature rotation
I am pretty new to blender and trying to solve a problem which is propably really easy.
I have two cylinders(picture below in BLUE) around which I wnat to shrinkwrap a third hollow cylinder(ORANGE). Affter the cylinder is shrinkwrapped around the blue cylinders I want to move the two (BLUE) cylinders(using armatures) up to 90 degreese as shown (Figure 3), with the ornage cylinder following this movement.
So far I was able to complete steps 1 and 2 but have some problems when it comes to moving the cylinders.The ends of the orange cylinder in my blender file dont seem to stick but rather rotate with the cylinders.
Is it possible to fix the end of the cylinders and just let the vertices in the middle deform? Ideally I want to see the vertex points around the rotation point stretching or contracting, depending on which side I rotate the cylinder.
Many thanks for any help!


Parent the orange thing to the armature as well and weight it half/half for each bone (just as you weighted the cylinders)
